# Speech to text for two edit texts (single button)

Tags: android

I'm new to Android Studio. I have tried Speech to Text with one edit text and it's working fine. But I want to apply Speech to Text for two edit texts with one button. Can anyone help me, please? I have tried from other resources but it's not working.

```
 <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:hint="phone"
        android:ems="10" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="text"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />
```

Here is the java code i want to apply speech to text through single button and two edit text .when the button is clicked it should roll down to next edit text and take the input

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        EditText tv1;
        EditText tv2;
        Button btn;
        private static final int REQUEST_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT = 1000;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            tv1 = findViewById(R.id.txt);
            tv2=findViewById(R.id.editText);
            btn = findViewById(R.id.button3);
            btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override 
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    speak();
                }

                private void speak() { 
                    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
                    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
                    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
                    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "say something");

                    try {
                        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT);

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        ///Toast.makeText(this,"",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                }

            });
        }
        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            switch (requestCode) {
                case REQUEST_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT: {
                    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {

                        ArrayList<String> result = data
                                .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                        tv1.setText(result.get(0));
                    }
                    break;
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you please mention what exactly do you want to show in those edittexts, you are speaking, getting the text from speech and then?? Do you want to show the text in both edit texts?

Comment: In 1st edit text it should take input as"number" and in 2nd edit text it should take input as "text" .plz help me

Comment: the number is taken from where exactly?

Comment: Any  number which i will be speaking.

Comment: ohhh so you want to filter what you're saying and based on the text, you would fill it inside the respective edittext?

Comment: Yes and with a single click it should take input for 1st and continue to 2nd edit txt

Comment: I want 1st input as "number" and 2nd input as "Text" with a single click

Comment: So let me get this straight:
You are going to speak randomly, you might say a normal speech or numbers.
If it is a number, it should be saved in input1. if it is a speech, it should display in input2. So the hard part here, is to detect whether the spoken text is actually a number or a text.

Comment: Is the behavior something like this?
"One burger" --> input 
Output: input1: 1, input2: burger?

Comment: No,Google voice input should be separate for two of the edit text. I mean to say on a single click it should take 1st edit text input and next move down to 2nd edit text to take input. The Google mic should reappear to take 2nd input

Comment: then you have to write some code in the onActivityResult. 
Let have a global variable, isFirst=ture;
onActivityResult, check if isFirst-> {
isFirst=false;
take input from second edittext;
}

Comment: if u don't mind can u elaborate, plz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before the onCreate:

```
private boolean isFirst=true;
```

Inside the onActivityResult:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT: {
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
                    if(isFirst){
                    isFirst=false;
                    ArrayList<String> result = data
                            .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                    tv1.setText(result.get(0));
                    //startAnother ActivityFor Result here but getting the second edittext
                   }else{
isFirst=true; 
}
            }
            break;
        }

        }
    }
```

Comment: anytime. Can you please accept the answer so that others can benefit as well?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try this

```
private void speak() { 
String speak = tv1.gettext().tostring()+" "+tv2.gettext().tostring();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
                    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
                    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
                    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT,speak);

                    try {
                        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT);

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        ///Toast.makeText(this,"",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
```

Comment: bro its not working actually. I mean to say that  when a button is clicked it should take input in 1st edit text as "number" and continue to second edit text as "text"

Comment: Google voice input should be separate for two of the edit text by single click.I mean to say on a single click it should take 1st edit text input and next move to 2nd edit text for input

Comment: I mean to say on a single click it should take 1st edit text input and next move down to 2nd edit text to take input. The Google mic should reappear to take 2nd input